# Android Studio: Timber: automatically add the function name

Tags: kotlin, timber

Does anyone know a trick to include the function name in a Timber text/tag without actually having to type it? Here's what I do and I figured I might as well ask... (initRecognizer is the function's name; ideally I enter something like $xyz)
Thank you

```
Timber.d("SR: initRecognizer psid=$psid")
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, Timber uses className as the tag. You can provide your own tag by overriding `createStackElementTag` function while planting the tree. Something like:

```kotlin
Timber.plant(
    object : Timber.DebugTree() {
        override fun createStackElementTag(element: StackTraceElement): String {
            val className = super.createStackElementTag(element)
            return "TAG $className ${element.methodName}"
        }
    }
)
```

I usually use a "TAG" prefix in my tags to quickly filter my logs from logcat.

Now you simply call `Timber.d("your debug msg")` and the function name will automatically be added in the tag in the logcat.